# Why is pandas groupby filter is slower than merge?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I've noticed that Pandas `groupby().filter()` is slow for large datasets. Much slower than the equivalent `merge`. Here's my example:

```
size = 50000000
df = pd.DataFrame( { 'M' : np.random.randint(10,size=size), 'A' : np.random.randn(size), 'B' :np.random.randn(size)})

%%time 
gb = df.groupby('M').filter(lambda x : x['A'].count()%2==0)

Wall time: 14 s

%%time
gb_int = df.groupby('M').count()%2==0
gb_int = gb_int[gb_int['A'] == True]
gb = df.merge(gb_int, left_on='M', right_index=True)

Wall time: 8.39 s
```

Can anyone help me understand why `groupby filter` is so slow?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the implementation of merge is based on a hashtable (on your 2nd example), while in your first example you might have an overhead with the test encapsulated in a lambda function ? (so its actually two separate guess, without any proof or anything, sorry if i'm wrong!)

Answer (score 1):

Using `%%prun`, you see that the faster `merge` relies on `inner_join`, `pandas.hashtable.Int64Factorizer` whereas the slower `filter` uses `groupby_indices` and `sort` (showing only calls consuming more than 0.02s):

```
         `merge`: 3361 function calls (3285 primitive calls) in 5.420 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    1.092    1.092    1.092    1.092 {pandas.algos.inner_join}
        4    0.768    0.192    0.768    0.192 {method 'factorize' of 'pandas.hashtable.Int64Factorizer' objects}
        1    0.578    0.578    0.578    0.578 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_float64_float64}
        4    0.512    0.128    0.512    0.128 {method 'take' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.425    0.425    0.425    0.425 {method 'get_labels' of 'pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable' objects}
        1    0.381    0.381    0.381    0.381 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis0_float64_float64}
        1    0.296    0.296    0.296    0.296 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_int64_int64}
        1    0.203    0.203    1.563    1.563 groupby.py:3730(count)
        1    0.194    0.194    0.194    0.194 merge.py:746(_get_join_keys)
        1    0.130    0.130    5.420    5.420 <string>:2(<module>)
        2    0.109    0.054    0.109    0.054 common.py:250(_isnull_ndarraylike)
        3    0.099    0.033    0.107    0.036 internals.py:4768(needs_filling)
        2    0.099    0.050    0.875    0.438 merge.py:687(_factorize_keys)
        2    0.094    0.047    0.200    0.100 groupby.py:3740(<genexpr>)
        2    0.083    0.041    0.083    0.041 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_bool_bool}
        1    0.081    0.081    0.772    0.772 algorithms.py:156(factorize)
        7    0.058    0.008    1.406    0.201 common.py:733(take_nd)
        1    0.049    0.049    2.521    2.521 merge.py:322(_get_join_info)
        1    0.035    0.035    2.196    2.196 merge.py:516(_get_join_indexers)
        1    0.030    0.030    0.030    0.030 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.putmask}
        1    0.030    0.030    0.033    0.033 merge.py:271(_maybe_add_join_keys)
        1    0.028    0.028    3.725    3.725 merge.py:26(merge)
       28    0.021    0.001    0.021    0.001 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
```

And the slower `filter`:

```
         3751 function calls (3694 primitive calls) in 9.110 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    2.158    2.158    2.158    2.158 {pandas.algos.groupby_indices}
        2    1.214    0.607    1.214    0.607 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_float64_float64}
        1    1.017    1.017    1.017    1.017 {method 'sort' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        4    0.859    0.215    0.859    0.215 {method 'take' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        2    0.586    0.293    0.586    0.293 {pandas.algos.take_2d_axis1_int64_int64}
        1    0.534    0.534    0.534    0.534 {pandas.algos.take_1d_int64_int64}
        1    0.420    0.420    0.420    0.420 {built-in method pandas.algos.ensure_object}
        1    0.395    0.395    0.395    0.395 {method 'get_labels' of 'pandas.hashtable.Int64HashTable' objects}
        1    0.349    0.349    0.349    0.349 {pandas.algos.groupsort_indexer}
        2    0.324    0.162    0.340    0.170 indexing.py:1794(maybe_convert_indices)
        2    0.223    0.112    3.109    1.555 internals.py:3625(take)
        1    0.129    0.129    0.129    0.129 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
        1    0.124    0.124    9.109    9.109 <string>:2(<module>)
        1    0.124    0.124    0.124    0.124 {method 'copy' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    0.086    0.086    0.086    0.086 {pandas.lib.generate_slices}
       31    0.083    0.003    0.083    0.003 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
        1    0.076    0.076    0.710    0.710 algorithms.py:156(factorize)
        5    0.074    0.015    2.415    0.483 common.py:733(take_nd)
        1    0.067    0.067    0.068    0.068 numeric.py:2476(array_equal)
        1    0.063    0.063    8.985    8.985 groupby.py:3523(filter)
        1    0.062    0.062    2.640    2.640 groupby.py:4300(_groupby_indices)
       10    0.059    0.006    0.059    0.006 common.py:250(_isnull_ndarraylike)
        1    0.030    0.030    0.030    0.030 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.putmask}
```